# Creating table using migration in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I am new in laravel.I was create table "users" using migration.But when I want create second one "timelog" using different migration, it gives error message 'table not found'. Then I delete all migration table and database table also. And I again I trying to create table "users" using migration.But the laravel gives error message in terminal. error messages are like:
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hrm.users' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `users` add `id` int u
  nsigned not null auto_increment primary key, add `username` varchar(255) not null, add `email` varchar(255) not null, add `c

  ontactnumber` varchar(255) not null, add `password` varchar(255) not null, add `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, ad
  d `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hrm.users' doesn't exist

How Can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app/database/migrations folder, if you migrate, Laravel will create all tables listed there which are not already on the migrations table.

The sql query suggests that you are trying to alter - not create - a table, so take a look at the migration classes and make sure they look something like this:

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateSomething extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('something', function($table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                ...
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            //drop the table
        }

    }
```